# CodeIgniter Rest API Authentication Digest

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I tried to follow the tutorial in NetTuts. I changed this

```
$config['rest_auth'] = 'digest'; 
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = array('admin' => '1234');
```

I typed the username and password, but I keep getting the login dialog over and over.

Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

to my .htaccess file was sufficient to get it working

Comment: what is the logic behind this, i want to know about this